# How to use html, java script with c++

Tags: javascript, c++, html, unix

I am very new to C++ and using Unix. I have a doubt that can we use C++ like JSP. For example consider a login page, Java script validate user inputs and passes that to C++ then C++ will check with database and return result html page. Can i do like this? If yes please help me how to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A programming language is a programming language. You just need a way to get the web server to pass data to and get data from the program you write.

Options include:

- [CGI](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html) is the simple, but slow and inefficient (because the server has to spawn a new process for every request), way.
- [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fastcgi-prog-guide/ch2c.htm) is better, but a bit more complicated.
- [Writing an Apache module](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565925670) is probably the hardest, but gives you a huge amount of power

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

Any language can do anything you want if you know how.

**Long Answer**

The original version of the Internet ran on C and Perl server side components using [Common Gateway Interface ( CGI )](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)

There are more modern implementations such as [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/).

In the end you need to have a Web Server to handle the HTTP portion, pick one that supports C++ plugins and use it.

[Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) is a nice new web server that should play nice with C++
[Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/) is a newer high performance low footprint web server that plays nice with C++

Apache is of course an old crusty but well documented popular option as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called, "CGI programming."

[Here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html) is a link explaining it.  It is not that difficult.  Basically, you would create an application and place it in a directory identified as containing cgi executables (commonly `cgi-bin` under the web root folder on unix-based systems).